# Two way synchronization in WinSCP

Tags: winscp

I am in an SSH session with a remote machine using WinSCP. I would like WinSCP to track a file on my local machine, call it `test.cpp`. That is, whenever this file is updated on my local machine, the change should automatically be made on the remote.

At the same time, I would like WinSCP to track a file on the remote, call it `out.txt`, so that changes to this file on the remote are reflected on my own machine.

How can I achieve both of these simultaneously? I want the first file to be tracked in one direction, and the other to be tracked in the other direction, but neither file should be tracked in both directions.

Comment: WinSCP is the wrong tool for this job.  If you are using UNIX/Linux and don't need literal immediate sync (e.g. syncing on a schedule is OK) look into `rsync`.

Comment: Actually I am looking for immediate synchronization. Also, my local machine is Windows (the remote is Ubuntu).

Comment: There's rsync for Windows (many UNIX/Linux utilities have Windows versions) - easy to find with search.  If you want immediate synchronization without repeated polling then you probably need a specialized tool (can't think of one designed just for this use), or setup a Samba server on the Ubuntu side and use Windows to access the Samba share.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a batch file that runs in a loop, running `put -neweronly` for `test.cpp` and `get -neweronly` for `out`:

```
@echo off
:loop
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 ...""" ^
    "put -neweronly C:\local\path\test.cpp /remote/path/*" ^
    "get -neweronly /remote/path/out C:\local\path\*" ^
    "exit"
timeout /t 30
goto loop
```

*([WinSCP GUI can generate a batch file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you)*

---

If you want to keep the connection open (not to reconnect for each iteration), you better use [WinSCP .NET assembly from a PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

See [Keep local directory up to date (download changed files from remote SFTP/FTP server)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_keep_local_directory_up_to_date) for an example.